# Domain host and localhost

Tags: jsp, servlets, host

I am doing my web-application project by using `jsp/servlets`. It works fine in `localhost`.

Now I had given the access to a `domain host` to upload my project through `FileZilla`. The `jsp` pages now displayed as source code instead of an interface of my project in the browser.

I never used domain host before. So what do I need to do so I can run my project in domain host just like it works in localhost?

Comment: have you installed tomcat on the other host? Your well application should be running in a tomcat instance. Then only the pages will be processed

Comment: Thank you very much @PrasadKharkar I will ask the person who owned the domain host.

Comment: By the way, could there have another reason in my situation? @PrasadKharkar

Comment: as far as I understand, you web app isn't deployed in a container yet, hence getting problem.

Comment: Alright. I will try to do that first. Thanks again @PrasadKharkar! :D